# Store hexdecimal value as byte results in missing

Tags: google-app-engine, go, byte, google-cloud-datastore

I tried to store a hexdecimal value like

```
url.Values{&#34;key&#34;: {&#34;Value&#34;}, &#34;id&#34;: {&#34;123&#34;}})
&#34;
```

in a []byte value on Google Appengine Datastore.

```
foo := Bar{
    HexdecimalContent:    []byte(content)
}
```

If I try to read this, all hexdecimal values    like &34; will result in a "(MISSING)" (other characters are shown correct!).
Now I save the data encoded in base64.

But why, is it needed to encode it in base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [encoding/json](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) package for serializing `map` types into the datastore

```
values := map[string]string{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
bytes, err := json.Marshal(values)
if err != nil {
    return err
}   
foo := &Bar{Content: bytes}
```